# How to add items to listview dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, listview-adapter

I am trying create an android app in Android studio that allows me to add items to my listView during runtime. I had a code used to add predefined items which worked when but when I modified it to add one item everytime I press the add button, I manage to add the first but when I try to add more after that, all the other items become the same as the first one.

Every item has a product id and a amount, in which the `idText` is set when my apps barcodescanner, scans a product, then I set the `amountText` by specifying a value in a `editText widget` and then create a item with these values by pressing the Add button. When I use it the first one ends up as it should like this:

```
778216562   12
```

but when I add another one, all previous items turns into the new one:

```
589095564   15
589095564   15
```

This is the code used to add items to my listView. The `addItem()` method is called when I press the add button on the app, also `listItem` is declared like this  `List<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<>();`:

```
 public void addItem(){
        if(amountText.getText().toString().matches("[0-9]+")) {
            productList.put(idText.getText().toString(), amountText.getText().toString());


            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[]{"idForID", "idForAmount"},
                    new int[]{R.id.productId, R.id.amount});

            resultsMap.put("idForID", idText.getText().toString());
            resultsMap.put("idForAmount", productList.get(idText.getText().toString()));
            listItems.add(resultsMap);

            productsView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
```

Does anyone know how to change this code so I can keep adding items without the previous one changing and while at it I am not able to add an item with the same product id as a previous one, but with a different amount and wonder if anyone knows how to resolve that as well?

Comment: it looks like you keep creating and setting a new adapter every time `addItem()` is called. Try moving your `SimpleAdapter` and your `productsView.setAdapter`to your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: why dont you use recyclerview

Comment: I have tried moving the SimpleAdapter and productsView.setAdapter to onCreate() but the same thing still happens. I haven't heard of recyclerview before but I can try to look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue is because of the way Java handles mutable data types. Since the `resultsMap` is a global variable, when you call `put()` with the same key value (i.e. `"idForID"` and `"idForAmount"`) you are overriding the last input for those keys. The reference `listItems` has still points to the `resultsMap` object that now contains the overridden data, leaving you with multiple copies of the same object.

A simple solution to this problem would be to move the declaration of the `resultsMap` object inside of your `addItem()` function (making it a local variable). Though I would also advise *against* this solution, considering the unnecessary added complexity of a `Map` nested inside of a `List`.

Instead, a solution that would also solve your second issue would be to create a class to contain the data.

```
final class Product(String id, String amount) {

    public final String id;
    public final String amount;

    public Product(String id, String amount) {
        this.id = id;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    /**
     * Override equals() and hashCode() as well.
     * These can be generated in Android Studio by selecting 
     * Code > Generate… > equals() and hashCode().
     */

}
```

Then use this object as the type for your list and adapter, instead of `Map<String, String>`, and make sure you create a new object each time you add an item to the list. This will allow you to create a `List` containing any amount of items, even if they have the same `id`.

---

As @Raza suggested, I would also recommend switching from a `ListView` to a `RecyclerView`. As stated in the [`ArrayAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) documentation.

> **Note:** If you are considering using array adapter with a ListView, consider using RecyclerView instead. [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) offers similar
>   features with better performance and more flexibility than ListView
>   provides. See the [Recycler View](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html) guide.

Comment: I have done as suggested and made a product class and using a RecyclerView instead of listView. Now it is working perfectly! Thanks a lot for all of your assistance!